# How to handle global Exception in ASP.Net MVC 2

Tags: exception, asp.net-mvc-2

My base controller has this override:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    // http://forums.asp.net/t/1318736.aspx
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }
    // If custom errors are disabled, we need to let the normal ASP.NET exception handler
    // execute so that the user can see useful debugging information.
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
    {
         return;
    }

    Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

    // If this is not an HTTP 500 (for example, if somebody throws an HTTP 404 from an action method),
    // ignore it.
    if (new HttpException(null, exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I want to catch the exception and mail it. I can do the mail part, but not sure how to gather the exception? I am new to MVC. In Web Forms I had this in global.asax

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string AdminEmail = "myEmail@domain";
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    string err = "Error Caught in Application_Error event\n" +
            "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
            "\n Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
            "\n Stack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
    // Below uses: using System.Diagnostics;
    //EventLog.WriteEntry("Sample_WebApp", err, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    //Server.ClearError(); // Clear error prohibits it from showing on page
    //additional actions...

    MyApp.Utility.Email.Send(AdminEmail, CommonLibrary.FromEmail, "Asp.net Application Error", err);
}
```

Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

Comment: You may take a look at [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Here's [an example](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC) with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement the same logic in your override method on base controller. Something like this:

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        string AdminEmail = "myEmail@domain";
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception objErr = filterContext.Exception;
        string err = "Error Caught in Application_Error event\n" +
                "Error in: " + Request.Url.ToString() +
                "\n Error Message:" + objErr.Message.ToString() +
                "\n Stack Trace:" + objErr.StackTrace.ToString();
        // Below uses: using System.Diagnostics;
        //EventLog.WriteEntry("Sample_WebApp", err, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        //Server.ClearError(); // Clear error prohibits it from showing on page
        //additional actions...

        MyApp.Utility.Email.Send(AdminEmail, CommonLibrary.FromEmail, "Asp.net Application Error", err);
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
```